# Disable OPTIONS method with .Net core 6.0 shows CORS error

Tags: .net-core, cors, http-options-method

For Security purpose, I have to disable OPTIONS method on IIS. My application is having .net Core WebAPIs. When  I disanble OPTIONS method on IIS, It starts showing CORS Error. Is there any other way, I can disable OPTIONS method in .Net core 6.0?